# Filter gremlin path by label and property

Tags: java, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I want to find all transitive relations (regardless of direction) by numbers of hops (2) with this traversal:

```
g.V(1).repeat(both()).times(2).path()
```

The result will look something like this:

```
==>[v[1], v[2], v[3]]
```

If I use by(label()) at the end of path():

```
==>[A, B, C]
```

If I use by('name'):

```
==>[R2, R1, R3]
```

But I cannot figure out how to mix the label and name together in the path result like this:

```
==>[A.R2, B.R1, C.R3]
```

I can already achieve the desired result with Java, but it costs a lot of iterations, converts and the performance is not great. Therefore I want to know if there is a native gremlin way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no support for String concatenation in TinkerPop, but you could do something like this:

```
g.V(1).
  repeat(both()).
    times(2).
  path().
    by(union(label(), values("name")).fold())
```

Comment: Thank you alot. It does similarly to what I want.